# hidden markov model with observation depending on multiple previous states

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, hidden-markov-models

I have a question, standard HMM the observation only depend on current hidden state O(i)|S(i),
for my problem, the observation is a outcome of a small continues region, say that O(i)|S(i-k,i-k+1..i-1,i) the k may vary for different i but a known value of o, are there any known method that can solve this kind of problem? I know if allow state change freely may make the computation unpractical, so some constrain may add such as if any state change happen, there will no change for next m position(m>>k), anyone have some idea about this kind of problem or reference?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16145681/2065121) to a similar question for some guidance.